# What is a Right-wing Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

---

If a word has a certain property, I call it a Right-wing Word™.

You can use the examples below to find the property:

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{Right-wing Words™}&\textbf{Not Right-wing Words™}\\
\hline
\text{ARM}&\text{HAND}\\
\hline
\text{BUMP}&\text{JERK}\\
\hline
\text{SECT}&\text{CASTE}\\
\hline
\text{CHILL}&\text{WARMTH}\\
\hline
\text{ACT}&\text{REAL}\\
\hline
\text{CRIMP}&\text{CURL}\\
\hline
\text{SWIM}&\text{DIVE}\\
\hline
\text{DRILL}&\text{PUNCH}\\
\hline
\text{KILL}&\text{MURDER}\\
\hline
\text{ASSERT}&\text{HIDE}\\
\hline
\text{SERUM}&\text{PILL}\\
\hline
\hline
\text{JUMP*}&\text{LEAP}\\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

For those without MathJax, or if you want to pop this into a spreadsheet, here is a CSV version:

```
Right-wing™,Not Right-wing™
    ARM,HAND
    BUMP,JERK
    SECT,CASTE
    CHILL,WARMTH
    ACT,REAL
    CRIMP,CURL
    SWIM,DIVE
    DRILL,PUNCH
    KILL,MURDER
    ASSERT,HIDE
    SERUM,PILL
    JUMP*,LEAP
   *- Only just a Right-Wing Word
```

<sub>P.S. my first puzzle. So, Do give your views.</sub>

Comment: Your keyboard is nonstandard.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A Right-wing™ word is a word ...

> which can be typed on the keyboard from left to right. Each character is either in the same column or to the right of the previous character.

<sub>PS: my first answer here ;-)</sub>

Comment: I would think CRIMP is problematic. But maybe it is just circumstantial. Especially, since JUMP is barely a Right-wing word (see OP's comment).

Comment: @Matsmath Why? C and R are in the same column, as are I and M (at least on my keyboard).

Comment: @randal'thor because J-U-M are in the same column (see [layout](http://www.kotovnik.com/~avg/rosetta/ascii-kbd.gif)).

Comment: @Matsmath I think the definition of a column can be hard to define. In this case the columns are probably QA, WSZ, EDX, RFC, TGV, YHB, UJN, IKM, OL, P

Comment: @IvoBeckers: On mechanical typewriters, the key levers are equally spaced in a linear row, but the levers have four different lengths to accommodate the four rows of the keypad (the shortest levers are for keys in the top row, and the longest are for keys in the bottom row), so the ordering of keys is unambiguous.  I'm not sure how well known actual typewriters are, these days.